# Install Diablo 3 on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: diablo-iii, linux, ubuntu

It looks like all Diablo 3 Linux/Ubuntu installation guides date from early 2015 and earlier. What is the easiest way to get D3 up and running in 2016?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, do yourself a favor and make sure you're using the right drivers. To see your video driver, run `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`. If you are rocking the integrated graphics and see the Intel driver, you're good. If you should be using nvidia drivers and don't see it there, either download the drivers straight from their website (and buy painkillers) or use [the Ubuntu repo](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

#### Install Diablo 3

1. **Install playonlinux**: `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`
2. **Install the latest version of wine-staging**: Tools > Manage Wine versions

   [image: Manage Wine versions][image: choose version]
3. **Create a new virtual drive**: Configure > New > 32-bit installation > pick the staging version you just chose > write any name (I wrote "D3")
4. **Select this drive in the Configuration menu (should be alongside default) and tab over to the "Wine" tab and click on "Configure Wine"** [image: Configure Wine]
5. A "Wine configuration" window will pop up. **Go to the "Libraries" tab and add these libraries**: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0, d3dcompiler_47, msvcp140, vcruntime140. Click Apply/Okay.

   [image: Wine configuration]
6. **Download the Windows D3 installer from Battle.net** ([direct link](https://www.battle.net/download/getInstallerForGame?os=win&version=LIVE&gameProgram=DIABLO_3))
7. Back in "PlayOnLinux configuration" **tab over to "Miscellaneous" and click "Run an .exe file in this virtual drive"**. Choose the installer you just downloaded and full steam ahead. If you have a non-standard configuration, you may need to search around for specific fixes (or revisit the driver check, if you skipped it above). Otherwise, you should be good to go!
8. (optional) Return to the "General" tab in your playonlinux configuration window and click "Make a new shortcut from this virtual drive" and select "Diablo III launcher.exe" to make future access easier.

Hopefully these fixes will be eventually wrapped into the default playonlinux wizard install.

Comment: There was a comment asking whether D3 on Linux is against Blizzard's terms of service or whether I knew anyone who was banned. Blizzard has an official response quoted [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/Blizzard-Perma-Bans-Linux-Users-From-Diablo-3-Lets-Botters-Continue-Play-44217.html) that Linux is not an issue as long as the files aren't modified, which they aren't in this installation. I haven't had any issues nor has anyone else informed me of their own.